# Angular Material table doesn't display data

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-table

I'm learning Angular material with Firebase as database. I tried to fetch all the data in the Firebase database but it's not showing in the Material table, I console log it and it retrieved the data. Problem is that the data is not showing in the HTML, I followed documentation on the table but still have the same issue.

Here's my HTML

```js
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Filter</mat-label>
  <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event)" placeholder="Ex. Mia" #input>
</mat-form-field>
    
<div class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>
  
    <!-- ID Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
       <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> ID </th>
       <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.id}} </td>
    </ng-container>
  
     <!-- First Name Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="firstName">
       <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> First Name </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.firstName}}% </td>
    </ng-container>
  
     <!-- Last Name Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="lastName">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Last Name </th>
       <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.lastName}} </td>
     </ng-container>
  
     <!-- Email Column -->
     <ng-container matColumnDef="email">
       <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Email </th>
       <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.email}} </td>
     </ng-container>
  
     <!-- Mobile Column -->
     <ng-container matColumnDef="mobile">
       <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Mobile </th>
       <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.mobile}} </td>
    </ng-container>

      <!-- BMI Result Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="bmiResult">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> BMI </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.bmiResult}} </td>
    </ng-container>

     <!-- Gender Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="gender">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Gender </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.gender}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Membership Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="membership">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Membership </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.membership}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Start Date Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="startDate">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Start Date </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.startDate | date}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Action Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="action">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Action </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> 
        <button>View</button>
        <button>Edit</button> 
        <button>Delete</button>
      </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
  
    <!-- Row shown when there is no matching data. -->
    <tr class="mat-row" *matNoDataRow>
      <td class="mat-cell" colspan="4">No data matching the filter "{{input.value}}"</td>
      </tr>
  </table>
  <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]" aria-label="Select page of users"></mat-paginator>
</div>
```

My TS file

```js
export class RegistrationListComponent implements OnInit {
  
public users!: User[];
public dataSource!: MatTableDataSource<User>;

@ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator!: MatPaginator;
@ViewChild(MatSort) matsort!: MatSort;
displayedColumns: string[] = ['id','firstName', 'lastName', 'email', 'mobile', 'bmiResult', 
  'gender', 'membership', 'startDate', 'action']

constructor(private api: ApiService){}

ngOnInit() {
  this.getUsers();
    
}
getUsers(){

this.api.getRegisteredUser().subscribe(result =>{
  if(!result){
    return;
  }
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.users);
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.matsort;
    console.log(result)
  });
}

applyFilter(event: Event) {
  const filterValue = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
  this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();

  if (this.dataSource.paginator) {
    this.dataSource.paginator.firstPage();
  }
 }
}
```

from Console after I refreshed the list component
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKE5G.png

Comment: Can you provide the response data as snippet? Thanks. From your code, you subscribe to observable, but you forgot to assign the value (`result`) to `this.users`.

Comment: @YongShun thank you! I assigned this.users to result. But I got new  TypeError: data.slice is not a function on component.ts: 39 and component.ts: 40

Comment: @YongShun I have this error before, I thought I solved this issue. But after I assigned the result to this.users, its back again.